# Concat not working in OnGetAsync Razor Pages

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, union, concatenation, razor-pages

No errors happen. Visual Studio .NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages builds and runs but only returns the data from the first Linq await. I am trying essentially to do a UNION by using the Concat method. I tried both Concat and replacing that with .Union but no luck, just the first query returns to Razor Page. The Razor Page is named "BoardMembers".

```
    public IList<OESAC.Models.BoardMembers> BoardMembers { get; set; }

  public IList<OESAC.Models.BoardMembers> BoardMembers2 { get; set; }


    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        // BoardMembers = await _context.BoardMembers.Where(x=> (x.Office !=null) && (x.WebDisplaySection =="Officers")).ToListAsync();

        BoardMembers = await _context.BoardMembers
            .Select(p => new OESAC.Models.BoardMembers
            {
                Office = p.Office,
                WebDisplaySection = p.WebDisplaySection,
                Representing = p.Representing,
                WholeName = p.WholeName
            }).Where(p=>p.WebDisplaySection == "Officers").ToListAsync();

        BoardMembers2 = await _context.BoardMembers
            .Select(p => new OESAC.Models.BoardMembers
            {
                Office=p.Office,
                WebDisplaySection=p.WebDisplaySection,
                Representing= p.Representing,
                WholeName=p.WholeName
            }).Where(p=> p.WebDisplaySection == "Board of Directors").ToListAsync();

        BoardMembers.Concat(BoardMembers2).ToList();

    }
```

The last line I have tried it with the ".ToList();" and without to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Concat you need to create a new list to hold the returned concatenated list.

```
 Var BoardMembers3 = BoardMembers.Concat(BoardMembers2).ToList();
```

You can however use AddRange to merge the Boardmembers2 list into Boardmembers.

```
BoardMembers.AddRange(BoardMembers2);
```

Comment: Bingo. Thank you very much! I couldn't get the AddRange to work until I changed the IList to List. Not sure what I gave up but it works perfectly for what I need.
Thanks!